# get html from website using express returns invalid header value char

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to get a website using express, and then send back the html to the application as a string.

It's working with google.com. However, it doesn't work with all sites.

the error is "Parse Error: Invalid header value char"

I'm not sure it's even making the request out.

I'm a beginner when it comes to this, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried specifying your `Content-Type` header value to `text/html`? Or can you please update your question to include your `server.js` so that we can see your code?

Comment: thank you! It's the simple things in life.